# Classify date/time by tidal states

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I want to classify `df1` date/time by tidal states given in `df2`. The thing with df2 is that it gives exact times when the tide was at its heighest as `HIGH` or `LOW`.

I want to change it so it classifies tidal height based on being within a 3-hour interval either side of `HIGH` and `LOW` tide.

```
 df1 <- data.frame(date_time = as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-06 09:00:00 BST", "2015-09-06 09:48:00 BST", "2015-09-06 10:37:00 BST", "2015-09-06 12:00:00 BST", "2015-09-06 12:48:00 BST","2015-09-06 13:35:00 BST")))

> df1
            date_time
1 2015-09-06 09:00:00
2 2015-09-06 09:48:00
3 2015-09-06 10:37:00
4 2015-09-06 12:00:00
5 2015-09-06 12:48:00
6 2015-09-06 13:35:00

df2 <- data.frame(Date_time = as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-06 07:09:00 GMT", "2015-09-06 13:18:00 GMT", "2015-09-06 19:52:00 GMT", "2015-09-07 02:01:00 GMT", "2015-09-07 08:28:00 GMT", "2015-09-07 14:43:00 GMT")), Tide_state = c("LOW",  "HIGH", "LOW",  "HIGH", "LOW",  "HIGH"))

df2
            Date_time Tide_state
1 2015-09-06 07:09:00        LOW
2 2015-09-06 13:18:00       HIGH
3 2015-09-06 19:52:00        LOW
4 2015-09-07 02:01:00       HIGH
5 2015-09-07 08:28:00        LOW
6 2015-09-07 14:43:00       HIGH
```

I've tried using `findInterval()`:

```
df1$tides <- df2$Tide_state[findInterval(x = df1$date_time, vec = df2$Date_time)]
```

Result:

```
df1
          date_time tides
1 2015-09-06 09:00:00   LOW
2 2015-09-06 09:48:00   LOW
3 2015-09-06 10:37:00   LOW
4 2015-09-06 12:00:00   LOW
5 2015-09-06 12:48:00   LOW
6 2015-09-06 13:35:00  HIGH
```

**Desired Result:** (based on tide being 3-hours either side of high and low.

```
df1
 date_time tides
    1 2015-09-06 09:00:00   LOW
    2 2015-09-06 09:48:00   LOW
    3 2015-09-06 10:37:00   HIGH
    4 2015-09-06 12:00:00   HIGH
    5 2015-09-06 12:48:00   HIGH
    6 2015-09-06 13:35:00   HIGH
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps `df2$Tide_state[pmax(findInterval(df1$date_time - 3600*3, df2$Date_time), findInterval(df1$date_time + 3600*3, df2$Date_time))]`

Comment: Thank you akrun - that worked! However - when applying to my main data I get `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "Tide_state", value = c("HIGH", "HIGH",  : 
  replacement has 259 rows, data has 260` I tried the `pmax(...)` bit isolated and works fine, giving a `length` of 260 but then when indexing it `df2$Tide_state[pmax(...)],  `length` is 259. Any ideas why?